# JHipster how to map each file name to its corresponding template class names?

Tags: java, templates, generator, jhipster, ejs

Suppose I'm generating three files (CassandraConfiguration0.java, CassandraConfiguration1.java, CassandraConfiguration2.java under a single template file (CassandraConfiguration.java.ejs):

```
{
        path: SERVER_MAIN_SRC_DIR,
        templates: [
            {
                file: 'package/config/cassandra/CassandraConfiguration.java',
                renameTo: generator => `${generator.javaDir}config/cassandra/CassandraConfiguration0.java`
            },
            {
                file: 'package/config/cassandra/CassandraConfiguration.java',
                renameTo: generator => `${generator.javaDir}config/cassandra/CassandraConfiguration1.java`
            },
            {
                file: 'package/config/cassandra/CassandraConfiguration.java',
                renameTo: generator => `${generator.javaDir}config/cassandra/CassandraConfiguration2.java`
            }
        ]
}
```

**How would I script CassandraConfiguration.java.ejs so that each file name is mapped to its corresponding class names?**

CassandraConfiguration.java.ejs:

```
public class CassandraConfiguration<%=???%>
```

**DESIRED OUTPUT:**

CassandraConfiguration0.java:

```
public class CassandraConfiguration0 {}
```

CassandraConfiguration1.java:

```
public class CassandraConfiguration1 {}
```

CassandraConfiguration2.java:

```
public class CassandraConfiguration2 {}
```

Comment: Have you tried using template's `context` property to pass class name?

Comment: Please explain what you mean by context property?

Comment: The key is to understand how the properties of the templates you define are used in `writeFilesToDisk()` function of generator-base.js, in particular the `options` property. Run the generator under node debugger and you will see how `options` property of a template object is passed to template file at runtime in the end by `template()` for rendering.

Comment: Is there a way to pass ${names} from files.js to templates directly?

Comment: can <%=???%> be dynamic by any chance? could it function like an array index: <%=name[i]%>